# HATEOAS - links are added on every single request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I have a rest API for class Tag, and want to add a link for each object.

but the duplicate link is added on every request(which calls the findAll() method).

**see the pictures below**

[tag after first request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrhGM.png)
[tag after many requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4jnA.png)

What should I change to make it appear only once?

Model -

```
public class Tag extends RepresentationModel<Tag> {
      ...
}
```

Controller -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("tags")
public class TagController {

private final TagService tagService;

@Autowired
public TagController(TagService tagService) {
    this.tagService = tagService;
}

@GetMapping()
public ResponseEntity<List<Tag>> findAll() {
    List<Tag> tags = this.tagService.findAll();
    List<Tag> response = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Tag t : tags) {
        t.add(linkTo(methodOn(TagController.class).find(t.getId())).withSelfRel());
        response.add(t);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Tag> find(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(this.tagService.find(id));
}
```

Comment: solved by using a new object as a copy of Tag t, in the loop